# IEnumerable.Cast Requirements For TResult

Tags: c#

The code probably explains it better than prose...  I should mention this is .NET 3.5.

**EDIT:** *Correctly formed* code would explain it better...  Sorry for the code in the initial post, and thanks for not down voting me as I deserved.

```
// WhichBox is a combobox that I am building a datasource for.  I want to
// display a 'pretty' name for my enum values, but get the actual enum
// value back upon selection
MyEnum typ;
List<KeyValuePair<MyEnum, string>> typs =
                        new List<KeyValuePair<MyEnum, string>>();
KeyValuePair<MyEnum, string> kvp;
WhichBox.Items.Clear();
foreach (string name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyEnum)))
{
  typ = (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), name, true);
  kvp = new KeyValuePair<MyEnum, string>
                 (typ, This.PrettyName(typ.ToString(), " "));
  typs.Add(kvp);
}
WhichBox.DataSource = typs;
WhichBox.DisplayMember = "Value";
WhichBox.ValueMember = "Key";
```

This works:

```
// Default to my desired value
WhichBox.SelectedItem =
    WhichBox.Items.Cast<KeyValuePair<MyEnum, string>>().First(
                       x => x.Key == MyEnum.MyDesiredDefault);
```

This gives an error I don't understand: Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'System.Type'.

```
WhichBox.SelectedItem =
    WhichBox.Items.Cast<kvp.GetType()>().First(
              x => x.Key == MyEnum.CapeToUser);
```

Answer (score 3):

The type argument of a generic is not allowed to be determined at run-time. You have to determine the type at compile time.

Your first example has the type explicitly set (compile-time), whereas your second example is using a run-time value. Hence, the error.

Comment: Essentially correct, although there are ways to instantiate specific types at runtime via reflection.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Absolutley, `Activator.CreateInstance` will do that. However, thats not a generic method :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Although you can use `dynamic` to (potentially) call a generic method with generic arguments not known until runtime.

Comment: @Servy I had thought of that, but I don't believe you can utilize that in a generic type argument itself. Is that correct?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET It won't work for this specific case.  The only way that `dynamic` would allow you to call a generic method with generic arguments only known at runtime is to leverage type inference.  If the generic type can be inferred (at least at runtime) then it can work.  `Cast` cannot ever infer the type, although you could write a method that could do what the OP is looking for by encapsulating that behavior in a method that *could* use type inference.  Of course, the whole idea of using `dynamic` rather defeats the purpose of using `Cast`, or any other option that defers type checking.

Comment: @Servy Ok, thanks for the clarification, that's basically what my understanding was (though you put it in far better words :) ).